# start-stop-daemon: command not found . This error only occurs at boot time in a cron job

Tags: cron, init.d, start-stop-daemon

I have scheduled an @reboot cron job to start a service in /etc/init.d

After boot, service is not started when I reach shell command line. The contents of /var/log/cron show the following,

```
2022-09-27T17:16:03.913135-04:00 mtcap CROND[2147]: (root) CMDOUT (Stopping cgbscript)
2022-09-27T17:16:03.927646-04:00 mtcap CROND[2147]: (root) CMDOUT (/etc/init.d/cgbscript: line 21: start-stop-daemon: command not found)
2022-09-27T17:16:03.933438-04:00 mtcap CROND[2147]: (root) CMDOUT (Starting cgbscript)
2022-09-27T17:16:03.948336-04:00 mtcap CROND[2147]: (root) CMDOUT (/etc/init.d/cgbscript: line 11: start-stop-daemon: command not found)
```

If those are cut off on your screen, the error reported twice is,

`start-stop-daemon: command not found`

When I reach my shell prompt I can perform

`# /etc/init.d/cgbscript start`

and everything is just fine. I do not see start-stop-daemon located in /bin/ nor is it located in /sbin/. I am unable to perform `# whereis start-stop-daemon` because this is a tiny embedded system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs are not executed in the same environment as the rest of the boot sequence. For this reason /usr/sbin/ is not in $PATH for those.

Alter the cgbscript so that start-stop-daemon appears with its absolute path.

`/usr/sbin/start-stop-daemon`

This fixes the problem.

Comment: Ох ксюша.......все то сама